# Cant display fetching data from JSON file using Axios - VUE3

Tags: json, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

im new to vue3 and axios and trying to read data from a json file locally stored. Bits of my json file are below.

```
[
{
  "brand": "air jordan",
  "id": 1,
  "slug": "air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-chicago-reimagined-lost-and-found",
  "name": "Jordan 1 Retro High OG Chicago Lost and Found",
  "model": "Chicago Lost and Found",
  "cheapestat": "stockx",
  "price": 370,
  "style": "DZ5485-612",
  "imageSrc": "nikeshoe",
},
{
  "brand": "air jordan",
  "id": 2,
  "slug": "air-jordan-11-retro-cherry-2022",
  "name": "Jordan 11 RetroCherry (2022)",
  "model": "Cherry (2022)",
  "cheapestat": "goat",
  "price": 335,
  "imageSrc": "jordanshoe",
},
{
  "brand": "air jordan",
  "id": 3,
  "slug": "air-jordan-4-retro-white-midnight-navy",
  "name": "Jordan 4 RetroMidnight Navy",
  "model": "Midnight Navy",
  "cheapestat": "foot locker",
  "price": 262,
 "imageSrc": "jordanshoe",
},
```

axios function below.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      sneakers: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
 axios
 .get('/src/stores/sneakers.json')
 .then(response => (this.sneakers = response))
 .catch(error => console.log(error))
  },
```

I am getting an error of "Cannot read properties of null" and nothing appearing. Not sure if the function or JSON file is correctly stated. Much appreciated.

Comment: have u tried to console log the response? probably u wanted to `... = response.data`

Comment: ah yes that works, i also realized i didnt have my v-for structured right. One more question if you can help. Looking to filter results to show a particular brand only (eg. Nike results). How would i do that? thanks

Comment: filter the array and search for a key containing the value u want - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter